# networkx.exception.NodeNotFound even if the node exists

Tags: python, image-processing, networkx, scikit-image

I'm using [sknw](https://github.com/Image-Py/sknw) for building graph from skeletonized image (The image is produced with [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/)). The problem is when I try to draw shortest path with any of the algorithm given in skimage **networkx.exception.NodeNotFound**. But the function **`graph.has_node()`** says that node exists.

Don't know what to do as stuck up for many days. Any help is appreciated.

***Code***

```html
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from skimage import data, io
from skimage.graph import shortest_path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sknw
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import numba


img = io.imread('m5_skeleton.png')
ske = skeletonize(img).astype(np.uint16)

# build graph from skeleton
graph = sknw.build_sknw(ske)

# draw image
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')

# draw edges by pts
for (s, e) in graph.edges():
    ps = graph[s][e]['pts']
    plt.plot(ps[:, 1], ps[:, 0], 'green')

# draw node by o
nodes = graph.nodes()
ps = np.array([nodes[i]['o'] for i in nodes])
plt.plot(ps[:, 1], ps[:, 0], 'r.')

print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('nodes')
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print(nodes)
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

# title and show
plt.title('Build Graph')
plt.savefig('m5_graph.svg', dpi=1200)

pos = nx.spring_layout(graph)
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('pos')
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print(pos)
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

# nx.draw(graph, pos, node_color='k')

# draw path in red
print('graph.has_node(0): ' + str(graph.has_node(0)))
print('graph.has_node(10): ' + str(graph.has_node(10)))

# source = graph.nodes[0]
# target = graph.nodes[2]

path = nx.astar_path(graph, graph.nodes.get(0), graph.nodes.get(10))
h = graph.subgraph(path)
path_edges = zip(path, path[1:])
path_edges = set(path_edges)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(h, pos, nodelist=path,  node_color='b', cmap='gray')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(h, pos, edge_cmap='gray')
plt.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

[image]
Above is **m5_skeleton.png** image I have used.

Comment: Can you give the full error message?  It would be helpful to see what line of code is producing the error.

Comment: When I use `io.imread` on the file you shared, I get an image of shape (1681, 1919, 4), that is, an RGBA image. Is that normal? For the rest of the code to work, it should be a *binary* image, meaning a NumPy array of dtype bool and shape (1681, 1919), with True where the skeleton is, and False elsewhere...

Comment: using `np.sum(img, axis=-1).astype(bool)` gets me a reasonable-looking skeleton. The next issue in your code is `ps = np.array([nodes[i]['o'] for i in nodes])`: `nodes` contains IDs. So it should be `graph.nodes[i]['o']`. **edit:** never mind, nodes is not a list of IDs, it's some fancier nx object.

Comment: @Juan as I mentioned earlier, I've used the image generated with scikit-image. I don't know if detection as RGBA with **io.imread()** is normal or not. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does "generated with scikit-image" mean? Do you have a source image and code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace:

```py
path = nx.astar_path(graph, graph.nodes.get(0), graph.nodes.get(10))
```

with

```py
path = nx.astar_path(graph, 0, 10)
```

That is, the function takes the *ID* of a node, not the node's contents, as input.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I replaced the code as you said. The code's working now, but the path isn't getting drawn in the graph. Can you please tell me what can be the issue now?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean it's not drawn in the graph. I get this: https://imgur.com/a/7wuk8HA Are you saying you want to overlay it on top of the image? Then you shouldn't use nx.spring_layout, as that will generate a layout based entirely on the graph shape, rather than the image positions. You should plot the path in the same way you plotted the skeleton graph (`for (s, e) in graph.edges():`), but use `h.edges()` instead

Comment: I mean't that the path wasn't getting drawn (overlayed) on the existing graph. Got the path drawn now. Can you please guide me the steps on how to get the drawn path on the original RGB image?

Comment: I mentioned above: you already have a loop where you draw all the edges in the graph. Repeat that loop, but use `h.edges()`, and of course change the color of the drawn edges so that you can distinguish them.